# Can't write to EEPROM on movesense device

Tags: movesense

I would like to write some values to EEPROM.
I'm doing the writing regarding to [movesense device documentation](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-docs/wiki/EmbeddedSoftware/api/components/eeprom.md).
It seems like onPutResult is never triggered and the device freezes after asyncPut.

This is my App.cpp:

```
#include "MoveWakeUpApp.h"
#include "movesense.h"

MOVESENSE_APPLICATION_STACKSIZE(1024)

MOVESENSE_PROVIDERS_BEGIN(1)

MOVESENSE_PROVIDER_DEF(MoveWakeUpApp)

MOVESENSE_PROVIDERS_END(1)

MOVESENSE_FEATURES_BEGIN()
// Explicitly enable or disable Movesense framework core modules.
// List of modules and their default state is found in documentation
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(DataLogger, false)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(Logbook, false)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(LedService, true)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(IndicationService, true)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(BleService, true)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(EepromService, true)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(BypassService, false)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(SystemMemoryService, false)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(DebugService, true)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(BleStandardHRS, false)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(BleNordicUART, false)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(CustomGattService, false)

// NOTE: It is inadvisable to enable both Logbook/DataLogger and 
EepromService without
// explicit definition of Logbook memory are (see LOGBOOK_MEMORY_AREA 
macro in movesense.h and eeprom_logbook_app).
// Default setting is for Logbook to use the whole EEPROM memory area.

// NOTE: If building a simulator build, these macros are obligatory!
DEBUGSERVICE_BUFFER_SIZE(6, 120); // 6 lines, 120 characters total
DEBUG_EEPROM_MEMORY_AREA(true, 0, 1024);
//LOGBOOK_MEMORY_AREA(0, 384 * 1024);

APPINFO_NAME("MoveWakeUp");
APPINFO_VERSION("1.0.0");
APPINFO_COMPANY("Movesense");

// NOTE: SERIAL_COMMUNICATION macro has been DEPRECATED
BLE_COMMUNICATION(true)
MOVESENSE_FEATURES_END()
```

Is there something I missed?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing it to my file App.CPP file I see that I have enabled SystemMemoryService. As well as the other services that I use with the EEPROM.

```
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(**DataLogger, true**)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(**Logbook, true**)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(LedService, true)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(IndicationService, true)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(BleService, true)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(**EepromService, true**)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(BypassService, false)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(**SystemMemoryService, true**)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(DebugService, true)
//DEBUGSERVICE_BUFFER_SIZE(6,120); // 6 lines, 120 chars total
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(BleStandardHRS, false)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(BleNordicUART, false)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(CustomGattService,false)

// NOTE: It is inadvisable to enable both Logbook/DataLogger and EepromService without
// explicit definition of Logbook memory are (see LOGBOOK_MEMORY_AREA macro in movesense.h and eeprom_logbook_app).
// Default setting is for Logbook to use the whole EEPROM memory area.
#define TIME_LENGTH 64
#define RESERVED  64
#define TOTAL_MEMMORY_SIZE (2097152 + 1048576) //read from the eeprom 
static const uint32_t offset = TIME_LENGTH + RESERVED;
static const uint32_t size = TOTAL_MEMMORY_SIZE - offset; // using all available space exept for space needed for persistant data
LOGBOOK_MEMORY_AREA(offset, size);
```

Could enabling SystemMemoryService be the solution to your problem?

As you can see I am also using the datalogger/logbook and setting aside some space in the EEPROM for other storage so not 100% sure what is needed for each of the services.

Comment: This fixed my problem! Thank you really much!

Comment: If it solved your question could you make my answer the answer to the question?